# error when i trying to connect No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to check if the user are connected and if it is on calendar/index
for that i created 2 method in the helper application

**application_helper**

```
def check_user_signed
  !user_signed_in?
end

def check_path_calendar
     current_page?(:controller => 'calendars', :action => 'index')
end
```

**my route files**

```
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'signup'}

resources :calendars
match 'calendars' => 'calendars#index', :as => 'calendars', :via => :get

#inforamtions 
match "information" => 'home#information', :as =>'information', :via => :get
```

When i trying to connect with my user i get an error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/calendars"}
```

Comment: what does your `rake routes` says ?

Answer (score 0):

This line is redundant:

```
match 'calendars' => 'calendars#index', :as => 'calendars', :via => :get
```

And it seems that error with this controller

Comment: If i remove this lign  match 'calendars' => 'calendars#index', :as => 'calendars', :via => :get

i have again the error

Comment: i have resolved my problem as this 

current_page?( :controller => '/calendars', :action => 'index')